# Making my own Functor typeclass in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, typeclass

So I wanted to make my own `Functor` to play around with typeclassing. However I ran into a bunch of issues. 
The endgoal is to be able to say something like `Seq(1,2,3).fmap(2*_)`.

I came up with this `trait` which all my Google searches (kind of) agree on:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](r: F[A], f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

I'm assuming there's no easy way to link the `A` to the `F[_]`, i.e. "`F[A]`".

But I'm having serious trouble creating an implicit to connect to `Seq`. Here's one try:

```
implicit class SeqFunctorOps[A](xs: Seq[A]) {
  def fmap[B](f: A => B) = xs map f
}
```

But that doesn't fit into my `Functor`, so let's extend it:

```
implicit class SeqFunctorOps[A](xs: Seq[A]) extends Functor[Seq] {
  def fmap[A, B](f: A => B) = xs map f
}
```

But that doesn't work because in `fmap[A, B]...`, the `A` is a new generic type, and doesn't tie in with `xs: Seq[A]`.

Is there a way to tie them in?

However, it also seems to me that `implicit class` is not the way to go, considering that other online resources have pointed to using the companion object, but I just can't seem to make it work.

```
object Functor {
  implicit def SeqFunctor: Functor[Seq] = new Functor[Seq] {
    def fmap[A, B](r: Seq[A], f: A => B) = r map f
  }
}

implicit class SeqFunctorOps[A](xs: Seq[A])(implicit F: Functor[Seq]) {
  def fmap[B](f: A => B) = F.fmap(xs, f)
}
```

This kind of seems to work, but looks off.

Is there a general pattern to use when trying to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Glory be to @drexin, this seems to be good enough:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](r: F[A], f: A => B): F[B]
}

object Functor {
  implicit def SeqFunctor: Functor[Seq] = new Functor[Seq] {
    def fmap[A, B](r: Seq[A], f: A => B) = r map f
  }
  implicit class Ops[A, F[_]: Functor](xs: F[A]) {
    def fmap[B](f: A => B) = implicitly[Functor[F]].fmap(xs, f)
  }
}
```

Comment: You only need the implicit or the context bound (F[_]: Functor). If you have the context bound you can get the implicit value with `implicitly[Functor[F]]`

Comment: I wouldn't place the context bound in the class tparams, because then the class can't be `AnyVal` and thus incurs a boxing penalty. I'd pass it as an arg to every method inside and make `Functor.Ops <: AnyVal`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Sorry, am new to Scala. Do you mean like `(implicit functor: Functor[F])`?